# How to pass value of input file and pass it to another method

Tags: java

This is what I have tried:
I have tried to print matrix in isDeadlock method ,output  is all zeros and seems like the value that called matrix after reading file is not kept and cannot be used in  method.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Findcycle {    
static int[][] matrix = new int[10000][10000];

    public static void main(String[] args) {      
        {

            int x=0, y=0;

            try
            {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("TestCase1.txt"));

                String line;
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)  
                {

                    String[] values = line.split(",");

                    for (String str : values)
                    {
                        int str_int = Integer.parseInt(str);
                        matrix[x][y]=str_int;

                        System.out.print(matrix[x][y] + " ");
                        y=y+1;
                    }
                    System.out.println("");
                    x=x+1;

                }   

                in.close();
                System.out.println(isDeadlock(matrix));

            }catch( IOException ioException ) {}

        }

    }
    public static class Node{
        int id;
        List<Node> getNodes = new ArrayList<Node>();
        public Node(int id){
            this.id=id;
        }
    }


    public static String isDeadlock(int matrix[][]){
        List<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<Node>();

       for(int i=0;i<matrix.length;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<matrix[i].length;j++) {
            System.out.println(matrix[i][j]);
            }
        }

  ...

    }
```

What should I do to fix this problem?
I am a newbie.
Thank you so much

Comment: I think you're going to need to give more description and details. What's the input? What output are you expecting? What's it actually giving you?

Answer (score 0):

When you are reading the file and filling the matrix you are not resetting y for each new line. So after `x=x+1;` you need to add `y = 0;` otherwise y will just continue to grow and all consecutive line will have there data offset more and more to the right.

Not a bug but since matrix is a static variable you don't need to send it as a parameter to isDeadlock.